# Storing a Boolean value in Redux so that I can use it in other pages to render something based on that value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, boolean, render

so I’ve the following code where I’m Destructuring the Boolean value isTrue from permissionSender, and I tried exporting that constant directly then imported to the file I want and render a warning message in UI

```
export let isTrue;
{isTrue:false}=permissionSender
```

Then I’ll import it wherever I want and do like below

```
{istrue &&<warningmessage>}
```

Now, when trying to write test case for this I couldn’t Mock the Boolean value as I’m getting “isTrue is readonly value” error, as such I did some research and it turns out this is a wrong implementation and we need to store this Boolean value in Redux then use it from there but I’m absolute beginner in React so Redux is way advanced for me.

So can someone please help me store this property in Redux, I’d appreciate for the same

Comment: Please don't try to do only a specific thing in Redux (which usually ends up in code you don't understand and can't maintain), but learn Redux first. [Start with the official tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts).
Also, you might not need Redux at all. Why are you not pass that value just as props?

Comment: @phry thanks for the advice, so after I posted this I followed the existing Redux code for different variables and implemented the same to mine as well, but I’m asking for learning purposes how do I pass a value as a props? I know how the props work when it comes to functions but unsure in this case, can you please share me a piece of code or something to understand this?

Comment: You pass that value as a component prop from the component that has the value to the component that needs it. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-props-to-a-component